# How to create a Wait() Method in C# XNA?

Tags: c#, xna, boolean, wait

I am trying to add in an "attract" mode in my game, for this I need to tell the character to wait before moving (so I can show text on screen). I decided it would be appropriate to make a Wait method in which I could send the following parameters.

```
    public bool Wait(int waitTime, GameTime gameTime)
    {
        // Wait Code
    }
```

The code would store the time that it was called, wait the specified time in milliseconds, and then return a true when the time has passed.

However I am not sure how to make it so that the gameTime is only stored on the first time Wait is called (or the bool never flags true). I thought I could make internal bools to handle the flagging but I am not sure how I would program this in a dynamic/reusable way?

Any help is greatly appreciated and sorry for the essay! <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved a similar problem. Here's the snippet:

```
private static readonly TimeSpan intervalBetweenAttack1 = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(3000); 
private TimeSpan lastTimeAttack;
```

and inside Update() of the updateable object

```
public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
      // If enough time has passed attack
      if (lastTimeAttack + intervalBetweenAttack < gameTime.TotalGameTime)
      {
           Attack();
           lastTimeAttack = gameTime.TotalGameTime;
      }
}
```

This is simplified code of AI. It attacks every 3 seconds. If you want to attack only one you can add bool hasAttacked = false; and then just simply check it in Update()

Answer (score 0):

You could create a timer class. Where you would do something like
Timer t = new Timer(3000f); //takes in a value to represent how long the timer runs for

Triggers:

```
t.Start();
```

Update method:

```
if(!t.IsActive)
{
    //Player updates here
}
else
    t.Update(gameTime);
```

Wait method:

```
public void Wait()
{
    if(t.IsActive)//set by the .start method
    {
        if(t.isComplete)
        {
             //do some stuff
             t.Stop();
        }
        else
        {
            //we're still timing, nothing to do here
        }
    }
}
```

This is very rough and written by memory, so not entirely sure if would help you.

So inside the timer class it increments during it's update and if a tracking float (something like currentTime += gameTime.elapsedgametime.milliseconds) is greater than the stored total time then mark the timer as IsComplete = true and then when this is true stop the timer running.

Therefore whenever the timer is running, the movement does not occur

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at Thread.Sleep, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.sleep%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: This is not an option in Xna, because you have to continue the game loop.

Comment: It would be an option if the Character movement was done on a seperate thread, but it is probably the dirtiest hack to get it working you could do. Well probably not. But point is it certainly is possible, but just not one I think anyone would advise.